# NuGet System.Drawing.Common .NET 6 CA1416 This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Image.FromStream(Stream)' is only supported on: 'windows'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Upgrading NuGet `System.Drawing.Common` to 6.0.0 causes the following error:

> CA1416 This call site is reachable on all platforms.
> 'Image.FromStream(Stream)' is only supported on: 'windows'.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/

The affected code is the following:

```
var drawingImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memstr);
```

We use the library to access the method `GetThumbnailImage`.

```
public byte[] GetThumbnailBytes(byte[] imageBytes)
{
    var thumbnailBytes = Array.Empty<byte>();

    using (MemoryStream memstr = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        var drawingImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memstr);
        var thumbnailSize = GetThumbnailSize(drawingImage);

        var thumbnail = drawingImage.GetThumbnailImage(thumbnailSize.Width, thumbnailSize.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        var ms = thumbnail.ToStream(drawingImage.RawFormat);

        thumbnailBytes = ms.ReadFully();
    }

    return thumbnailBytes;
}
```

We only host the application on Azure so targeting Windows is fine but replacing `GetThumbnailImage` is acceptable as well.

Comment: If you vote down please say why. Very hard to improve a question otherwise.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:**

Targeting Windows worked fine until one of our developers tried to start the solution on his Apple computer using `Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Preview 1`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416

Reading .NET 6 Breaking changes Microsoft has a section about `System.Drawing.Common`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only

Their recommendations are the following:

> To use these APIs for cross-platform apps, migrate to one of the
> following libraries:
>
> - [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp)
> - [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)
> - [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics)
>
> Alternatively, you can enable support for non-Windows platforms by
> setting the System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport runtime configuration
> switch to true in the runtimeconfig.json file:

```
{
   "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
         "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
      }
   }
}
```

> This configuration switch was added to give cross-platform apps that
> depend heavily on this package time to migrate to more modern
> libraries. However, non-Windows bugs will not be fixed. In addition,
> we may completely remove support for non-Windows platforms in a future
> release, even if you enable it using the runtime configuration switch.
>
> Note
>
> Despite the name of the runtime switch,
> System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport, it applies to various non-Windows
> platforms, such as macOS and Android, which can generally be
> considered flavors of Unix.

Even though `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics` is in preview and is considered an experimental library I tried to use it given that Microsoft has the library as a recommended action library.

It seemed really promising at first but then I encountered a bug in their `IImage Downsize` method.

https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/issues/247

Until that is fixed my temporary solution is using Target framework .NET 6, Target OS (none) and then use `Exclude specific warnings as errors` given that we have enabled `Treat warnings as errors`.

[image]

I have also created a `runtimeconfig.template.json` in our web project root with the following values:

```
{
   "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
         "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
      }
   }
}
```

**Original:**

After reading about the breaking change on Microsoft Docs and since we only target the Windows platform I decided to do the quickest path to victory for the moment and set Target OS to `Windows`.

[image]

> But this code won't warn if the project targets Windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/code-analysis/5.0/ca1416-platform-compatibility-analyzer

Comment: the only fix i needed was the json file. But the syntax was a little wrong for me. It needed to be as described below by Mehmet https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286035/3093731
 {
    "configProperties": {
        "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
    }
}

Comment: Tried Microsoft.Maui.Graphics for reading width and height from an uploaded image and they were wrong (or anyway not in pixel, but width was a negative value so don't really know), SkiaSharp looks working great!

Answer (score 2):

.NET 6 Breaking changes Microsoft has a section about **System.Drawing.Common**

1. add your project **runtimeconfig.template.json**

```json
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
  }
}
```

2. add your **DockerFile** this or install your linux container

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libc6-dev \
        libgdiplus \
        libx11-dev \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: all i needed was the json file - Thanks!

Comment: some functions will work with docker file. if you take an exception like gdi+ error. you should update dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

This has been an long open [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14502)

[I have got around it](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14502#issuecomment-760087905) by editing my shared assembly info (not autogenerated) with

```
#if NET6_0
[assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows7.0")]
#endif
```